# Thread Safety when using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I have the below code.

ServiceA.m1() is getting called by multiple threads from another class.Is the below code Thread safe?If yes then why?

```
@Service
ServiceA
{

@Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;


m1(OrderInfo orderInfo)
{


///changing object values
orderInfo.setTime(..);
orderInfo.setId(..);


 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        serviceB.m2(orderInfo)
    },myCustomExecutor);
}
```

}

Comment: Based on the posted code, `ServiceA` doesn't have any state other than to `ServiceB` which appears to just be a delegate, so if `ServiceB` is thread safe (stateless) then `ServiceA` is thread safe.  To ensure the services are stateless mark any delegates as final, e..g, immutable classes are thread safe.

Comment: @AndrewS It's annotated with `Service` annotation (Spring Boot).So it's singleton bean

Comment: Please use code examples that compile correctly rather than pseudo-code.